# Converting an "enter" in \n in a text file

Tags: php, forms, text, include

I have a program that adds the content of a text box into a text file which I include on another page, the problem is that the include doesn't automatically create a new line where it is in the text file.

How do i do this?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is with viewing the newlines in the actual text box, \r\n, \r, or \n should do it (depending on your OS). Alternatively, if you want to view said newlines on the web you would use echo nl2br( $txt )

Comment: Used echo nl2br(file_get_content($textfile));

Answer (score 3):

not sure what your asking, but a common mistake is assume the line break in a texatarea will be formatted in html for you, it wont. but in php you can just use the function nl2br() to convert a line break to the html `<br>`

Comment: I also need to display the text in the text file as it should be formatted ie. without </br> tags and already with new lines (not \n). Any tips on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using double quotes around your `\n` operator.

```
$text = "first line of text";
$text .= "\n" . $newText;
```

**Edit:**

Or save a new line to a variable:

```
<?    
    $newline = '
';
    $text = "first line of text";
    $newText = 'second line';
    $text .= $newline . $newText;
    echo $text;
```

http://codepad.org/pplKTiCN

Comment: I'm not using \n in the text box because it is for someone who doesn't know php and I was wondering how to do it so they don't see that sort of thing. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = strip_tags($text, '<br>');
```

or you can replace the br tag using

```
$text = str_replace ('<br>', "\n", $text);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

also check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

You can append a `\r\n` to the end of the text in the textbox.

```
$textToAppend=$textInTextbox . '\r\n'
```

The `\r\n` is the line break character sequence in Windows.
`\r` means carriage return and `\n` means newline
The ASCII code foe `\r` is `0x13` and for `\n` is `0x10`